# I'm getting a color and decoration null error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-test

HELP!!
Please i'm getting this error

color == null || decoration == null
"Cannot provide both a color and a decoration\nTo provide both, use "decoration:
BoxDecoration(color: color)"."
The relevant error-causing widget was:
AppIconText
AppIconText:file:///Users/jessezephyr/projects/flutter/ticketapp/lib/screens/search_screen.dart:67:17

This is the code

````
`flutter`
{

    ```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_layout.dart';

import '../utils/app_styles.dart';

class AppIconText extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  const AppIconText({super.key, required this.icon, required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: AppLayout.getWidth(12),
          horizontal: AppLayout.getHeight(12)),
      color: Colors.white,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppLayout.getWidth(10)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            color: const Color(0XFF8FC20F),
          ),
          Gap(AppLayout.getWidth(10)),
          Text(
            text,
            style: Styles.textStyle,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

}

{

````
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_layout.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/utils/app_styles.dart';
import 'package:ticketapp/widgets/icon_text_widget.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = AppLayout.getSize(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Styles.bgColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: AppLayout.getWidth(20),
            vertical: AppLayout.getHeight(20)),
        children: [
          Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(40)),
          Text(
            'What are you \nlooking for?',
            style:
                Styles.headLineStyle.copyWith(fontSize: AppLayout.getWidth(35)),
          ),
          Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(20)),
          FittedBox(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.5),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  /* 
                Airline TICKETS
                 */
                  Container(
                    width: size.width * .44,
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: AppLayout.getHeight(7)),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                          left: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(50))),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Airline tickets')),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: size.width * .44,
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: AppLayout.getHeight(7)),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                          right: Radius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(50))),
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Hotels ')),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppLayout.getHeight(50)),
                color: const Color(0xFFF4F6FD),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(25)),
          const AppIconText(
              icon: Icons.flight_takeoff_rounded, text: 'Departure'),
          Gap(AppLayout.getHeight(15)),
          const AppIconText(icon: Icons.flight_land_rounded, text: 'Arrival'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

    ```

}

It's supposed to display an icon and text
````

It's supposed to display a text and an icon but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppIconText widget, the Container widget being returned has both color and decoration defined. This is not allowed as stated in the error message. A container should either have a color or decoration or none. You can not have both color and decoration on a container. This is because a box decoration itself has a color property. If you are using a decoration, you should use this property to assign color to the Container.

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: AppLayout.getWidth(12),
    horizontal: AppLayout.getHeight(12)),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(AppLayout.getWidth(10)),
        color: Colors.white,
    ),
    ......
);
```

Just move the color property inside the BoxDecoration and it will work.